# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^m}{n^{m+1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

By considering:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^1}{n^{2}} = \frac 1 2$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}{n^{3}} = \frac 1 3$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^3}{n^{4}} = \frac 1 4$$

Determine if this is true:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^m}{n^{m+1}} = \frac 1 {{m+1}}$$

If it is, prove it.

If it is not, evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^m}{{m+1}}$.

Comment: Please use LaTex for your question.

Comment: See [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63986/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sums-of-consecutive-powers).

Comment: Thx Thomas Andrews to LaTex it for me!

Comment: I've edited the question to LaTeX, but there was a clear error in your original question which I left in - you ask if: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^m}{n^{m+1}} = \frac 1 {n^{m+1}}$$ But the left hand side is a limit as $n$ varies, and the right hand side still has $n$. I think the right hand side should be $\frac 1{m+1}$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478344/what-is-the-result-of-lim-n-to-infty-frac-sumn-i-1-iknk1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This follows easily from a comparison with an integral.

Since
$$\int_0^{n} k^m dk \leq \sum_{k=1}^n k^m \leq \int_1^{n+1} k^m dk,$$
we have
$$\frac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}\leq   \sum_{k=1}^n k^m \leq \frac{(n+1)^{m+1}}{m+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}.$$
Divide by $n^{m+1}$ to get
$$\frac{1}{m+1} \leq \frac{1}{n^{m+1}}  \sum_{k=1}^n k^m \leq \frac{1}{m+1} \cdot \frac{(n+1)^{m+1}}{n^{m+1}} - \frac{1}{m+1} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{m+1}}.$$
Taking $n \rightarrow \infty$ gives the desired result.

Comment: This is a valid answer, and will probably be of use to more advanced readers. However, the question was tagged [tag:algebra-precalculus]. Another answer utlizing calculus would be to approximate the Riemann integral by$$\int_0^1x^m\,\mathrm{d}x =\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^m\frac1n$$

Comment: Can you please further explain about $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m\leq \int_{1}^{n+1}k^mdk$ ?

Comment: Is it clear that $k^m \leq \int_k^{k+1} x^m dx$? This is because when $k\leq x \leq k+1$, $k^m \leq x^m$. Integrate this to get $k^m \leq \int_k^{k+1} x^m dx$. Sum this over $k$ from $1$ to $n$ to get the inequality. Then replace $x$ with $k$.

Comment: Very simple, thanks.

Comment: Evidently, I was wrong about the usage of calculus in a problem tagged algebra-precalculus.

Comment: I don't recall limits being taught in pre-calc. Horizontal asymptotes, perhaps, but not limits.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a poor question- tagger.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is tagged [algebra-precalculus](/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus), I will refrain from using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula (which is exact in the case of polynomials).

Let's first show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^m\text{ is a polynomial of degree }m+1\text{ in }n\text{ whose lead coefficient is }\frac{1}{m+1}\tag{1}
$$

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n1=n$, we have shown that $(1)$ is true for $m=0$.

Suppose that $(1)$ is true for all $m<M$, then
$$
k^{M+1}-(k-1)^{M+1}=\sum_{m=0}^{M}\binom{M+1}{m}(-1)^{M-m}k^m\tag{2}
$$
If we sum $(2)$ for $k$ from $1$ to $n$, the telescoping sum on the left yields
$$
n^{M+1}=\sum_{m=0}^{M}\binom{M+1}{m}(-1)^{M-m}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^m\right)\tag{3}
$$
Isolating the $m=M$ term from the right-hand side of $(3)$ gives us
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^M=\frac{1}{M+1}n^{M+1}-\frac{1}{M+1}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\binom{M+1}{m}(-1)^{M-m}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^m\right)\tag{4}
$$
Since $(1)$ holds for each $m<M$, each $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^m\right)$ on the right-hand side of $(4)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $m+1<M+1$. Thus, because of the $n^{M+1}$, the right-hand side of $(4)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $M+1$ whose lead coefficient is $\dfrac{1}{M+1}$.

Thus, we have shown $(1)$ for all $m\ge0$.

Consider
$$
\frac{1}{n^{m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^m\tag{5}
$$
The sum in $(5)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $m+1$ whose lead coefficient is $\dfrac{1}{m+1}$. Therefore, $(5)$ becomes
$$
\frac{1}{m+1}+O\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{6}
$$
Thus, we get that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\;\frac{1}{n^{m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^m=\frac{1}{m+1}\tag{7}
$$

Comment: Does $O$ notation apply to precalc?

Comment: @Peter: I don't know in what order things are taught in various places, but limits and big-O notation are very closely related.

Answer (score 7):

If you are familiar with it, this is a standard application of [Stolz-Cesàro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

SC says that this limit is the same as

$$\lim_n \frac{(n+1)^m}{(n+1)^{m+1}-n^{m+1}}$$

It is an easy exercise (I'll leave this part to you) to prove that this limit is exactly $\frac{1}{m+1}$.

**P.S.** Stolz-Cesàro is for sequences exactly what l'Hôpital is for functions.

Answer (score 0):

What is true is that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^m = {n^{m + 1}\over m+1} + P_m(n),$$
where $\deg(P) <= m.$
Dividing you will get
$${1\over n^{m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n k^m = {1\over m+1} + {1\over n^{m+1}}P_m(n)
= {1\over m+1} + O(1/n). $$

Answer (score 0):

By induction, using binomial theorem and telescoping, we have that

$$(k+1)^{m+1}-k^{m+1} = (m+1)k^{m} + O(k^{m-1}) $$$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^nk^m =\frac{(n+1)^{m+1}}{m+1}+O(n^m)=\frac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}+O(n^m)$$

and the resul follows.