# What is the result of $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum^n_{i=1} i^k}{n^{k+1}},\ k \in \mathbb{R} $ and why?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the result of the next limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum^n_{i=1} i^k}{n^{k+1}},\ k \in \mathbb{R} $$

**Why (theorem)?**

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150391/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac-sum-k-1n-kmnm1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p}=\frac{1}{p+1} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050057/prove-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1np1-sum-k-1nkp-frac)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply [Lemma Stolz-Cesaro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum^n_{i=1} i^k}{n^{k+1}}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (n+1)^k}{(n+1)^{k+1}-n^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Comment: How do you get $ 1/(k+1) $?

Comment: @David as n gets huge the fraction in the limit basically becomes ... logic doesn't apply, Look closely. $(n+1)^{k+1}$ and $n^{k+1}$ are not actually that far apart. Yeah they are for k=1 and n from 4 to 5 say (25-16 = 9, not a small amount!) but after a while they come close to each other (look at the graph of their ratio for some powers, it is interesting) but they are not the same, the denominator tends towards 0 from above (as k gets large) but the numerator also gets huge. So the thing should get huge! If you do 1/ limit you get something that looks like 1 for huge k.

Comment: @David that contradicts (it looks like $n+1-n\frac{n^k}{(n+1)^k}$ and that last fraction tends towards 1 from below. So we have tends towards 0 from above +1, which is 1, 1/1 is 1. This is why you need to be careful with things that go near 0 in the denominator. 1 and $+\infty$ are both wrong for huge k! So that $\frac{1}{k+1}$ comes from some special place, it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 7):

This is a Riemann sum, which in this limit takes on the value of an integral:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^k}{n^k} = \int_0^1 dx \, x^k = \frac{1}{k+1}$$

so long as $k \gt -1$.

Comment: As long as $k > -1$.

Comment: Because the LHS goes to $+ \infty$, while the RHS is negative? Sure, you can probably define your answer as some kind of sum of a divergent serie, but that's not the answer to David's problem.

Comment: Could one apply the Stolz–Cesàro theorem?

Comment: The numerator converges to a positive constant. The denominator goes to $0$. The answer is straightforward.

Comment: @D.Thomine: what was I thinking?  Yes, of course, thank you.

Comment: @David: I don't know.  If I were comfortable with it, and it were true, then I would have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify Ron's answer, the result you're looking for is the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{K}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f\left(\frac{Ki}{n}\right)=\int_0^K f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
In your case, $f(x) = x^k$, and $K=1$. The trick here is that whenever you deal with the limit of a sum, factor outside the sum $1/n$ and see whether you can group the sum term to reduce to the Riemann sum expression. If you can, switch to integral form.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}i^{k} \over n^{k + 1}}:\ {\large ?}.
     \qquad k \in {\mathbb R}}$.

---

1. $\ds{\large\dsc{k < -1}:}$
   \begin{align}&\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}i^{k} \over n^{k + 1}}
   =\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\pars{%
   n^{\verts{k + 1}}\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}{1 \over i^{\verts{k}}}}
   =\color{#66f}{\large\infty}
   \end{align}
   Note that
   $\ds{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}{1 \over i^{\verts{k}}}=\zeta\pars{\verts{k}}}$
2. $\ds{\large \dsc{k = -1}:}$
   \begin{align}&\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}i^{k} \over n^{k + 1}}
   =\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}{1 \over i}=\color{#66f}{\large\infty}
   \end{align}
   Note that
   $\ds{\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}{1 \over i}=H_{n}}$ where $\ds{H_{n}}$ is the *Harmonic Number* which diverges *logarithmically*
   $\ds{\pars{~H_{n} \sim \ln\pars{n}\ \mbox{when}\ n \gg 1~}}$.
3. $\ds{\large \dsc{k > -1}:}$
   \begin{align}\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}i^{k} \over n^{k + 1}}
   &=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
   {\sum^{n + 1}_{i\ =\ 1}i^{k} - \sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}i^{k}\over
   \pars{n + 1}^{k + 1} - n^{k + 1}}
   =\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
   {\pars{n + 1}^{k} \over \pars{n + 1}^{k + 1} - n^{k + 1}}
   =\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over k + 1}}
   \end{align}