# Computing a tricky limit

Tags: calculus

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^m + 2^m + 3^m + \cdots + (2n-1)^m }{n^{m+1}} $$

I am kind of stuck since I cannot make it look into a form that would involve the integral of certain function. I know somehow it would be easy if we can compare this limit to a Riemann sum. Any ideas?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq   and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478344/what-is-the-result-of-lim-n-to-infty-frac-sumn-i-1-iknk1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Notice sum and integral are asymptotic of each other. Both are polynomials so this implies their main terms are equal. 
This justifies the answers below ; the limit must exist and must be the one by the integral. This is sketchy ofcourse but the main idea.

Answer (score 18):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^{2n-1}_{k=1} \frac{k^m}{n^m n} = \sum^{2n-1}_{k=1} \left(\frac{k}{n} \right)^m\frac{1}{n} \approx \int^2_0 x^m\ dx.
\end{align}

Comment: The $\approx$ should be $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$

Comment: @jwg I know. I wanted the reader to think a little.

Comment: can you give some more details into the solution? thanks!

Answer (score 5):

16 years later: More details (see Jacky's answer)
$$
\frac{1^m + 2^m + 3^m + \cdots + (2n-1)^m }{n^{m+1}}
=\frac{1}{n} \left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^m
+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^m
+\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)^m + \cdots
+\left(\frac{2n-1}{n}\right)^m
\right]
$$
Recognize this as a Riemann sum for $\int_0^2 x^m\;dx$, where
the interval $[0,2]$ is subdivided into $2n$ equal-size intervals,
and the function is evaluated at the left endpoint of each interval.  Then cite appropriate theorems to show (a) that $x^m$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, and (b) these Riemann sums converge to the integral.

---

Remark.  In this proof, the value $m$ could be any nonnegative real number.  Or even any complex number with nonnegative real part.

The integral converges for $-1<m<0$, but the elementary reasoning here will not show that the Riemann sums converge to the integral.

Comment: +1 Nice to answer this old question.
Although I think it can be improved, it is already a big improvement.
I think it can be shown in a different way, with a difference operator.