# Limit of a Riemann sum $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^p}{n^{p+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^p+2^p+\ldots+n^p}{n^{p+1}}=$$
I managed to simplify it down to
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \left(\frac1n\right)^p \cdot \frac1n + \left(\frac2n\right)^p \cdot \frac1n + \ldots + \left(\frac{n}{n} \right)^p \cdot \frac1n \right)=$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^p \frac{1}n$$
How should I calculate this limit?

Comment: Can you express that limit as an integral (as the title of your question seems to imply)?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478344/what-is-the-result-of-lim-n-to-infty-frac-sumn-i-1-iknk1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150391/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac-sum-k-1n-kmnm1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote $1^p + 2^p + \cdots n^p = P_p(n)$. This is a polynomial of degree $p+1$ and is given by
$$P_p(n) = \frac1{p+1} \sum_{k=0}^p \dbinom{p+1}{k} B_k n^{p+1-k}$$ where $B_k$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). These polynomials are related to the [Bernoulli polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials) and there are some really nice results on these polynomials and more can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials).

Hence, $$\dfrac{P_p(n)}{n^{p+1}} = \dfrac1{p+1} \sum_{k=0}^p \dbinom{p+1}{k} B_k n^{-k} = \dfrac1{p+1} \left(B_0 + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac1{n}\right) \right)$$
where $B_0 = 1$, $B_1 = \frac12$, etc. Now conclude what you want.

You might also be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149142/lim-n-to-infty-left-frac1p2p3p-cdots-npnp-fracnp1).

Comment: This is nuking mosquitoes. The OP has asked what appears to be a simple Riemann integral.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan This is in fact the proof for the "simple Riemann integral".

Comment: The proof for the simple Riemann integral is called the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Use $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

to $$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac in\right)^p$$ here $\displaystyle f\left(\frac in\right)=\left(\frac in\right)^p$

Comment: @vilbur, what if $p=-1$?

Comment: at p=-1 the given limit become $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}$ which is diverging,so limit diverges