# Proving $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^a}{n^{a+1}}=\frac{1}{a+1}$

Tags: limits, summation

How do we prove that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^a}{n^{a+1}}=\frac{1}{a+1}$$?

This type of terms appear in problems on limits, but I am unable to prove this.

Please help me out.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478344/what-is-the-result-of-lim-n-to-infty-frac-sumn-i-1-iknk1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150391/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac-sum-k-1n-kmnm1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx,$$

we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac rn\right)^a=\int_0^1x^a\ dx$$

Comment: What if the sum would be from $r=1$ to $n-1$ instead of $n$?

Comment: @Lover, $$-f\left(\dfrac nn\right)=?$$

Comment: Yes, it is one. But still I don't see the right reasoning. My problem is that I have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i^{a-1}}{n^a}=\dfrac{1}{a}$.  The solution is very similar to this written above, but still I don't catch it because of this $n-1$ above the sum. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @Lover,   $$\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}f(r/n)=-f(n/n)+\sum_{r=1}^nf(r/n)$$ right?

Comment: Yes, I see. Now everything is clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: I would like to additionally ask if the result depends on value of $a$?

Comment: @Lover, What if $$a+1=0?$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use L'hopital's rule as

> $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^a}{n^{a+1}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\displaystyle n^a}{(1+a)n^{a}} = \frac{1}{a+1}$$

Comment: How have you evaluated the derivative of the numerator?

Answer (score 1):

It also follows from the Cesaro theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the:
$$\sum_{r=1}^nr^a=1^a+2^a+\dotsb+n^a$$
part. **It turns out that this is a polynomial, whose leading term is $\dfrac1{a+1}r^{a+1}$.** For example:

\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^nr^1&=\frac12n^2+\frac12n\\
\sum_{r=1}^nr^2&=\frac13n^3+\frac12n^2+\frac16n\\
\sum_{r=1}^nr^3&=\frac14n^4+\frac12n^3+\frac14n^2\\
\sum_{r=1}^nr^4&=\frac15n^5+\frac12n^4+\frac13n^3-\frac1{30}n\\
\sum_{r=1}^nr^5&=\frac16n^6+\frac12n^5+\frac5{12}n^4-\frac1{12}n^2
\end{align}

How to prove?

One thing to note is that if:
$$\sum_{r=1}^nf(r)=S(r)$$
then:
$$S(r)-S(r-1)=f(r)$$
(prove this!). Also note that $x^{a+1}-(x-1)^{a+1}$ is a polynomial whose first term is $(a+1)x^a$ (prove this too!). Can you use these facts to prove the statement in bold above? (Once you have this, it's easy to answer the stated problem.)