# Limit of the sequence $\frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{n^{k+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How would someone find the limit of the sequence $a_n = \frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{n^{k+1}}, k \in \mathbb{N}$ as $n$ goes to Infinity?
Can someone give me maybe a hint where to start?

Comment: Have you heard of Riemann sums yet?

Comment: You didn't say what constraints you might be working under, but if one of them is that you're not allowed to use integration methods, see my [23 October 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5297748) for an outline of a proof that involves only mathematical induction and high school algebra (and limits to infinity of rational functions).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/150391).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition of the Riemann integral we have:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^k=\int_0^1 x^k dx=\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Comment: can you prove this?

Comment: This is by the definition of the Riemann integral. @VictorKolobov

Comment: @YourAdHere: it would be nice to mention that you are using Riemann Sums *in the question*.

Answer (score 4):

We will prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \frac{1}{k+1}$ by elementary means by showing that $$1^k + 2^k + \ldots + n^k$$

can be written as a polynomial of degree $k+1$ in $n$ with leading term $\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}$.

Define the following polynomial (of degree $k$ in $n$)

$$p_k(n) = {n\choose k}k! = n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1) = n^k + a_{k-1,n}n^{k-1} + \ldots + a_{1,n}n + a_{0,n}$$

We can now choose $b_{i}$ s.t.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k}b_{i}p_i(n) = n^k$$

This is done by taking $b_{k}=1$ and then choosing $b_{i}$ (from $i=k-1$ down to $i=0$) s.t. the coefficient of the $n^i$ term vanishes.

We can now write

$$ 1^k + 2^k+\ldots + n^k = \sum_{m=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^kb_{i}p_i(m)$$

and by using the identity $\sum_{m=0}^n{m\choose i}={n+1\choose i+1}$ we finally arrive at

$$ 1^k + 2^k+\ldots + n^k = \sum_{i=0}^kb_{i}{n+1\choose i+1}i! = \sum_{i=0}^k\frac{b_{i}p_{i+1}(n+1)}{i+1} = \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1} + A_kn^k + \ldots + A_1n$$

and the claim follows. I might add that this proof can with some more work be made constructive by deriving the explicit form for all the $A_{i}$ coefficients and thereby giving us an [explcit formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Sum_of_powers) for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$.

Answer (score 3):

We have by the Riemann sum

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k=n^{k+1}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac in\right)^k\sim_\infty n^{k+1}\int_0^1 x^kdx=\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}$$
so we see easily that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac1{k+1}$$