# How to do this limit: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\large\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^p}{n^{p+1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

$$\large\lim_{n\to \infty}\large\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^p}{n^{p+1}}$$

I'm stuck here because the sum is like this: $1^p+2^p+3^p+4^p+\cdots+n^p$.

Any ideas?

Comment: See also: [Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^m}{n^{m+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150391#181062) and [other posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/150391).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then:

> $$
> \int_a^b f(x)~dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f \left(a + k \left(\dfrac{b-a}{n}\right) \right)
> $$

Can you rewrite the given sum in the above form? What might be an appropriate choice for $a$, $b$, and $f(x)$?

Comment: Where did you get this mighty theorem from? does it have a name?

Comment: It's the limit definition of an integral, via Riemann sums.

Comment: It's made by this way. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

By Writing *limit-of-sum* as Integral we get

> $$ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\large\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^p}{n^{p+1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^p}{n\cdot n^p}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^p=\int_0^1 x^p dx=\frac{1}{p+1}$$

Comment: @Joseph, Integrator used the first formula given by Adriano with $a=0$, $b=1$, $f(x)=x^p$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: This hint is probably a hammer but still worth it.
Faulhaber's formula states that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^p = \dfrac1{p+1} \sum_{j=0}^p (-1)^j \dbinom{p+1}j B_j n^{p+1-j}$$