# Is there a general product formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm familiar with Faulhaber's formula to express this sum as a much simpler one, but it appears that for any $p$ there's a product formula in $n$ for the sum e.g.:

$$\begin{align}
& \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^1=\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
& \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\
& \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}
\end{align}$$

...and so forth. Is there a general product formula in $p$ and $n$ for this sum?

Comment: Yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula.

Comment: Could you explain it a little better?

Comment: See [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Sum_of_powers).

Comment: But in general I would not call it a "product formula".  The polynomials usually do not have only linear factors.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63986/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sums-of-consecutive-powers

Answer (score 4):

This question was answered in a comment:

> Yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula. –  Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla Feb 1 at 22:31