# Formula to obtain sum of $ 1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+(n-1)^k+n^k$

Tags: induction

How would one systematically obtain the formula for $$ 1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+(n-1)^k+n^k$$ for a fixed positive integer exponent k?
I am aware of the formulas $$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}\quad ,\quad\sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\quad,\quad\sum_{i=0}^n i^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$ i.e. when values of k are 1, 2 and 3. Using these can I use induction to proceed with the original sum?

Comment: You're looking for [Faulhaber's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html), see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1667258/201168) for its derivation.

Comment: Do you necessary want a proof using induction or are Ok with a different  approach?

Comment: @OlivierOloa I can go for a different approach, but i wanted to see if induction could handle it

Comment: @Workaholic, Thankyou very much....I appreciate your help very much

Comment: @AyanShah You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach. One may use the [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Representations) satisfying $$B_{k+1}(x+1)-B_{k+1}(x)=(k+1)x^k$$ then, one gets $$\sum_{j=1}^n (k+1)j^k=\sum_{j=1}^n (B_{k+1}(j+1)-B_{k+1}(j))$$ but this is a *telescoping sum* giving

> $$
> \sum_{j=1}^n j^k=1^k+2^k+3^k+....+(n-1)^k+n^k=\frac{B_{k+1}(n+1)-B_{k+1}(1)}{k+1}.
> $$