# General formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{N} k^n$?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a general formula for

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N} k^n
$$

for integers $n \geq 1$? Wolfram alpha linked me the harmonic number but it doesn't seem to expand beyond negative values since $\Gamma(-n)=\widetilde{\infty}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Faulhaber's formula derived?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667258/how-is-faulhabers-formula-derived) or if you are not interested in that, then possible duplicate of [Methods to compute $\sum_{k=1}^nk^p$ without Faulhaber's formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035188/methods-to-compute-sum-k-1nkp-without-faulhabers-formula)

Comment: For $n=1,2,3$ we have general formulae. https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/

Comment: Thank you!! Sorry, did not know the name.

Comment: No problemo!  =D