# Formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^x=?$

Tags: linear-algebra

I wanted to know if there is a formula for ∑nk=1kx∑k=1nkx?

For example, for $x = 1$ we have : $N (N + 1) / 2$.

Also, for $x = 2$ we have : $N ( N + 1 ) ( 2n + 1 ) / 6$.

Comment: You are looking for *Faulhaber's formula* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Well I know that: $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^3 = \bigg(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k\bigg)^2$$ That is a formula for $x = 3$. I am not aware of a general formula concerning any value for $x$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Faulhaber's formula derived?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667258/how-is-faulhabers-formula-derived)