# A formula for $1^4+2^4+...+n^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation, integers, telescopic-series

I know that 
$$\sum^n_{i=1}i^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$
and 
$$\sum^n_{i=1}i^3=\left(\sum^n_{i=1}i\right)^2.$$
Here is the question: is there a formula for 
$$\sum^n_{i=1}i^4.$$

Comment: Yes, in fact continuing the trend of your other examples, it is a polynomial in $n$ of order 5. If you calculate the first few terms, you should be able to figure it out. However you should be careful about notation in your sums, and not use $n$ both as the upper limit and as the number counting up.

Comment: Does it mean $\sum i^n = $ polynomial of degree n+1?

Comment: I just edited. Thank you.

Comment: you may want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @Huang thanks for that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667258/how-is-faulhabers-formula-derived, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035188/methods-to-compute-sum-k-1nkp-without-faulhabers-formula

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can get the formula by the following way.

$$(n+1)^5-1=\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)^5-k^5)=\sum_{k=1}^n(5k^4+10k^3+10k^2+5k+1).$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^4=$$
$$=\frac{1}{5}\left((n+1)^5-1-10\cdot\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}-10\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-5\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-n\right)=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}.$$

Answer (score 3):

It is interesting to note that
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n i^{\,4}
&=\frac 1{30}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)\\
&=\frac{3n^2+3n-1}5\cdot\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 \\
&=\frac{3n^2+3n-1}5\sum_{i=1}^n i^{\,2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Your last line should be multiplied by $\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven - Thanks for spotting the typo. Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a formula, $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^4=1/30\,n \left( 2\,n+1 \right)  \left( n+1 \right)  \left( 3\,{n}^{2}+3
\,n-1 \right) 
$$

Comment: How is this derived?

Comment: It is probably correct and if you can prove that formula that will be great.

Comment: this is correct, can you do it by induction?

Comment: But how to come up with it initially?

Comment: here you can find a proof https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-generate-a-formula-for-sequences-like-1-4+2-4+3-4+-+n-4-n-1+n-1+2n-1+3n+3n2-30

Comment: I have seen the site and it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: ok nice that i helped you!