# Proof of sum formula, no induction

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

So I was trying to prove this sum formula without induction. I got some tips from my textbook and got this.

Let $S=1+2+\cdots+n-1+n$ be the sum of integers and $S=n+(n+1)+\cdots+2+1$ written backwards. If I add these $2$ equations I get $2S=(1+n)+(1+n)\cdots(1+n)+(1+n)$ $n$ times.

This gives me $2S=n(n+1) \Rightarrow S=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ as wanted.

However if I changed this proof so that n was strictly odd or strictly even, how might I got about this. I realize even means n must be $n/2$. But I haven't been able to implement this in the proof correctly.

Edit: error in question fixed, also by $n/2$ I mean should I implement this idea somewhere in the proof, cause even means divisible by $2$.

Comment: When written backward, $S=n+(n-1)+....+2+1$

Comment: "I realize even means n must be n/2". I'm confused. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof for formula for sum of sequence $1+2+3+\ldots+n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn)

Comment: To say "$n$ must be $n/s$" is a confusion.  Better is "$n= 2m$ for some integer $m$."  Your proof works for both odd and even $n$, so your last para is mysterious.  Do you mean that you want to add just the first $n$ odd (or even) integers?

Comment: the proof works whether $n$ is even or odd. what's the problem? You realize that either $n$ or $n+1$ will be even.

Comment: I was confused cause my textbook splits this question up, they say prove it for when n is even and proves it when n is odd. i assumed it would be a different proof sicne there 2 different questions.

Comment: you can see proof without words sum of n integers .https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Richards31975.pdf

Comment: "However if I changed this proof so that n was strictly odd or strictly even, how might I got about this."  Proving a general case, will prove restrictive case.  You proved it was true for *ALL* numbers.  So it is true for odd numbers.  And it is true for all even numbers.  There is nothing to prove.  By adding them twice you get $2S = n(n+1)$ and that handles all cases.  If you have a nagging doubt "but how did the universe make is so that $n(n+1)$ has to always be even" notice that if n is odd n+1 is even.  And if n is even, n is even.

Comment: "I was confused cause my textbook splits this question up" When I did this problem the very first time, my instinct was to add 1 and n, and 2 and (n-1) and so on.  If n is even I get $\frac n2$ pairs adding to $n+1$.  If $n$ was odd, I got $\frac {n-1}2$ pairs adding to $n+1$ and an single middle term that was $\frac {n+1}2$.  That gave me the same result.  However, if you add the $S$ twice, that actually takes care of both cases in one fell swoop.

Comment: @Shanen Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: (requires you to consider whether $n$ is odd or even.)

$S = 1 + 2 + ...... + n$.

Join up the first to term to the last term and second to second to last and so on.

$S = \underbrace{1 + \underbrace{2 + \underbrace{3 +....+(n-2)} + (n-1)} + n}$.

$= (n+1) + (n+1) + .....$.

If $n$ is even then:

$S = \underbrace{1 + \underbrace{2 + \underbrace{3 +..+\underbrace{\frac n2 + (\frac n2 + 1)}+..+(n-2)} + (n-1)} + n}$

And you have $\frac n2$ pairs that add up to $n+1$.  So the sum is $S= \frac n2(n+1)$.

If $n$ is odd then:

$S = \underbrace{1 + \underbrace{2 + \underbrace{3 +..+\underbrace{\frac {n-1}2 + [\frac {n+1}2] +  (\frac {n+1}2 + 1)}+..+(n-2)} + (n-1)} + n}$

And you have $\frac {n-1}2$ pairs that also add up to $n+1$ and one extra number $\frac {n+1}2$ which didn't fit into any pair.  So the sum is $\frac {n-1}2(n+1) + \frac {n+1}2 =(n-1)\frac {n+1}2 + \frac {n+1}2 = (n-1 + 1)\frac {n+1}2n=n\frac {n+1}2$.

Method 1$\frac 12$ (Same as above but waves hands over doing tso cases).

$S = average*\text{number of terms} = average*n$.

Now the average of $1$ and $n$ is $\frac {n+1}2$ and the average of $2$ and $n-1$ is $\frac {n+1}2$ and so on.   So the average of all of them together is $\frac {n+1}2$.  So $S = \frac {n+1}2n$.

Method 2: (doesn't require considering whether $n$ is odd or even).

$S = 1 + 2 + 3 + ...... + n$

$S = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ...... + 1$.

$2S = S+S = (n+ 1) + (n+1) + ..... + (n+1) = n(n+1)$>

$S = \frac {n(n+1)}2$.

Note that by adding $S$ to itself this doesn't matter whether $n$ is even or odd.

And lest you are wondering why can we be so sure that $n(n+1)$ *must* be even (we constructed it so it must be true... but why?) we simply note that one of $n$ or $n+1$ must be even.

So no problem.

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ even i.e. $n=2m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $S:=1+2+...+2m$ then

$$2S=S+S=(1+2+...+(2m-1)+2m)+(2m+(2m-1)+...+2+1)=((1+2m)+(2+(2m-1))+...+((2m-1)+2)+(2m+1))=\underbrace{((2m+1)+...+(2m+1))}_{2m-times}=(2m+1)\cdot 2m$$
Therefore $$S=\frac{(2m+1)2m}{2}=m(2m+1)$$
Analogue for $n$ odd. The formula is the same as in general for any $n$. You indeed just substitute directly into it. For instance
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{2m(2m+1)}{2}=m(2m+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

This classical result can be also easily proved by the following trick

[image]

An extended discussion also for more general cases here [How Are the Solutions for Finite Sums of Natural Numbers Derived?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664218/how-are-the-solutions-for-finite-sums-of-natural-numbers-derived/2664224#2664224)

Answer (score 0):

A combinatorial proof. Consider the two element subsets of $\Omega=\{0,1,\dotsc,n\}$. There are $\binom{n+1}{2}$ of them (corresponding to the right hand side of the equality). But we can count in another way. Classify the two element subsets based on their maximum element. For $1\leq k \leq n$, there are $\binom{k}{1}=k$ two element subsets whose maximum element is $k$ since there are $k$ non-negative integers less than $k$.

Another proof based on telescoping. Let $n^{\underline{2}}=n(n-1)$ (this is the falling factorial of length two. The exponent has an underline for notation). Observe that
$$
\frac{1}{2}(n+1)^{\underline{2}}-\frac{1}{2}(n)^{\underline{2}}=n.
$$
In particular
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)^{\underline{2}}-(k)^{\underline{2}}=\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{2}}}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$