# Summation of simple series $\sum_{r=5}^n (2r + 4r^2) $

Tags: summation

I am trying to teach myself, but I am confused on one question. It says "for the following summation, give an equivalent equation without the summation:

$$\sum_{r=5}^n (2r + 4r^2) $$ where $i$ takes values from $5$ to $n$.

Comment: `confused on one question` The question implies that you must have seen something at least remotely similar in the past. What's different here, what did you try, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @jessica.m Since you are new here, recall also that you can accept an answer among the given, more details here [LINK](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\sum 2i+4i^2=2\sum i+4\sum i^2$$

and

$$\sum_5^n a_n=\sum_1^n a_n-\sum_1^4 a_n$$

then refer to the [sum of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples) formulas.

Refer also to the related [How Are the Solutions for Finite Sums of Natural Numbers Derived?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2664218/505767)

Comment: Really thank you sooo much, very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

---

Seems to be a high school level problem :
$$\sum_{r=5}^{n}2r+r^2=2\sum_{r=5}^{n}r+\sum_{r=5}^{n}r^2
$$
$$=2\bigg(\sum_{r=1}^{n}r-\sum_{r=1}^{4}r\bigg)+\bigg(\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^2-\sum_{r=1}^{4}r^2\bigg)$$
$$=2\bigg(n-\frac{5\times4}{2}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}-9\frac{(4^2+4)}{6}\bigg)$$

---

solve it to get your answer.

Comment: Really thank you sooo much, very helpful.