# Help me to find the limit of the given function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, physics

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\:\: \frac{1+2+3+...x}{x^2} $$
How can I find the limit of above expression. Please tell me which identities and theorems to apply.

Comment: Is $x$ an integer number?

Comment: Yes it is a integral number

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667258/how-is-faulhabers-formula-derived

Comment: Nope it's another question

Comment: @gauss19, it looks exact same question to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the sum of the first $n$ numbers corresponds to

$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

This means

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks ☺️ I got it.