# Asymptotic behavior of sums of consecutive powers (bivariate)

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

Are there some (bivariate) closed form formulas for the asymptotic behaviour
of the sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^d,$$

where $n$ and $d$ are large integers?
I am especially interested in a lower bound of the form $\Omega(f(n,d))$.
I am aware there is an exact formula as a polynomial involving the Bernouilli numbers, and the asymptotic behavior has been discussed in [some other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63986/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sums-of-consecutive-powers) question when $d$ is fixed, but here I consider both $n$ and $d$ as unbounded.

Comment: It's bounded below by $n^{d+1}/(d+1)$; does this suffice?  If there was more information about how the size of $n$ compares to the size of $d$ then it might be possible to get a better estimate.

Comment: No, there is no other information.