# On asymptotic properties of the sum of consecutive powers

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

For positive integers $p, n$, the sum of consecutive $p$-th powers is
$$
S_p(n) := \sum_{k=1}^n k^p.
$$
From [Asymptotic behaviour of sums of consecutive powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63986/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sums-of-consecutive-powers?rq=1) we have that $S_p(n)/n^{p+1}$ is decreasing when viewed as a function of $p$ (with $n$ fixed). Can we be more precise? Say can we compute the limit of $S_p(n)/n^{p+1}$ as $p \to \infty$? Thanks.

Comment: I am not following: since $n$ is fixed, it suffices to compute the limit of $k^p/n^{p+1}$ for each $1\le k\le n$. Is this out of reach?

Comment: since $n$ is fixed, I don't think that Riemann Sums are really applicable

Comment: Oh I see. You guys are funny :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$ \frac{S_p(n)}{n^{p+1}} = \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{1}{n^p} + \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^p +  \dotsb +  \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^p + 1 \right). $$
Now, $n$ is fixed, so if we take the limit as $p \to \infty$, we can push it inside the sum. Every term in the sum is the $p$th power of a number in $(0,1)$ apart from the last one. Therefore every term in the sum tends to zero except the last one, and
$$ \lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{S_p(n)}{n^{p+1}} = \frac{1}{n}. $$

Comment: But the number of terms in the sum is also a function of $p$.  Something needs to be said to justify interchanging the sum and limit.

Comment: @JairTaylor: no, $n$ is fixed. The number of terms does not change. I was about to post the same answer (with some notation changes), so I am pretty sure that this is correct.

Comment: Thanks Chappers. Seems correct and the data confirms this too.

Comment: @robjohn Ah, I see, you are correct.