# Is there any formula for this sum of power of positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analysis, additive-combinatorics

I wonder if there is any formula for this sum.
$$k^\gamma+(k-1)^\gamma+\cdots+1^\gamma,$$
where $k$ is positive integer and $\gamma\in(0,1)$. And how about $\gamma<0$? Or is there any known asymptotic when $k$ tends to infinity?

Comment: The closest result is the Faulhaber's formula, which compute the sum $k^n+(k-1)^n+...+1^n$ as a function of $k$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: For any $s > 0, \notin \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^p n^s - \zeta(-s) \asymp \frac{1}{s+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{s+1}{k} (-1)^k B_k p^{s+1-k}$$
This is an exercise in Frank W.J. Olver's book "Asymptotics and Specical Functions".  
Look at $\S8.3$ "Contour integral for the remainder term" for more details.

Comment: Are these not the generalised harmonic numbers in reverse order, with the sign of the exponent reversed - $H_{n,m}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^m}+...+\frac{1}{n^m}$ ?

Comment: For the case $0< \gamma <1$, may be this post can help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63986/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sums-of-consecutive-powers/64000#64000

Comment: you can bound it by $\frac{(k+1)^{\gamma +1}-1}{\gamma +1}$ and $\frac{k^{\gamma +1}-1}{\gamma +1}$.

Comment: For $k \to \infty$ and $\gamma < -1$, the sum becomes $\zeta(-\gamma)$.  But this may not be a case you're interested in.

Comment: @Famke : This is NOT a duplicate. The posting to which you linked is about positive integer exponents; this one is about exponents between $0$ and $1. \qquad$

Answer (score 4):

The sum gives $\sum _{j=1}^k j^\gamma = H_k^{(-\gamma)}$ which is the harmonic number of order $\gamma.$

An excellent approximation I have found is

$$\sum _{j=1}^k j^{\gamma}\approx \left(\frac{\gamma}{12 k}+\frac{k}{\gamma+1} + \frac{1}{2}\right) k^{\gamma}+\frac{1}{2} \gamma \log (2 \pi )-\frac{1}{2}$$

for $\gamma=0.5$ I got the following results. It is an asymptotic approximation, so it works better for large $k$. For negative $\gamma$ the approximation works fine if $|\gamma|<0.5$

$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
k & H_k^{(-\frac12)}& \textit{approximation}\\
\hline
 1 & 1 & 1.1678 \\
 11 & 25.7849 & 25.9523 \\
 21 & 66.2486 & 66.4159 \\
 31 & 117.651 & 117.818 \\
 41 & 178.019 & 178.186 \\
 51 & 246.177 & 246.345 \\
 61 & 321.319 & 321.487 \\
 71 & 402.848 & 403.015 \\
 81 & 490.297 & 490.464 \\
 91 & 583.289 & 583.457 \\
 101 & 681.513 & 681.68
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be studied here:

[The generalization of Faulhaber's formula to sums of non-integral powers](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X06008791)
(McGowna. Parks - Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications - v 330, 1, 1 June 2007)

There it's proved that

$$ (a+1) \sum_{n=1}^N n^a = N^\gamma F_a(N) + (a+1) \zeta(-a)+O(N^{-\beta})$$

where $a\ge -1$ and non integer (actually it's also valid for complex $a$ with real part greater than $1$), $\beta = m -a$, $m=\lfloor a+1 \rfloor $, $\gamma = -(m-a)$ and

$$F_a(N)=N^{m+1} + \sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k {a+1 \choose k}B_k N^{m-k+1}$$

with $B_k$ denoting Bernoulli numbers.