# Finding the Limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} +\cdots+ \sqrt[3]{n})/n^{\frac{4}{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} +\cdots+ \sqrt[3]{n}}{n^{4/3}}$$

My work:

I was just following suit in the book I read, so I came up with this solution to get the limit above:

$$\int_0 ^1 \sqrt[3]{x} \, dx = \frac{3}{4}$$

The problem is, the way I solved the problem above, I did not think what is the signficance
of the denominator, which is $n^{\frac{4}{3}}$. I might have the same solution to the problem, as
long as i see the $\sqrt[3]{n}$  at the end, not minding the denominator.

What is the correct approach in getting the limit above?

Comment: Try to write the Riemann sums for the integral.

Comment: can you write what you did?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it directly translated into the Riemann sum of the integral you mentioned.

Comment: @Rigel My book did not tell me about a Riemann sum.....XD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asymptotic behaviour of sums of consecutive powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63986/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sums-of-consecutive-powers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum can be written
$$\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{\frac kn}$$
which is a Riemann sum for the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: I must remember that form......the coefficient is $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{k}{n}$ becomes $x$ always....

Comment: Wait...the original form is $\frac {1}{n^\frac{4}{3}}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{\frac kn}$ ? and when modified, it becomes   $\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{\frac kn}$? how did you modified it? from $\frac {1}{n^\frac{4}{3}}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{\frac kn}$  to  $\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{\frac kn}$?